# Иконка в диалоге не выводится у 5-й версии Андроид

Tags: java, android

Не пойму почему!
Во вложении исходный текст и результаты работы эмуляторов разных версий.

[Ссылка на иконку](http://iconbird.com/view/4403_iconki_home_dom)

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static int sW;
    private int sH;
    public static Float dens;
    public static int newW;
    public Bitmap im;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        int height = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        int width = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        dens = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        sW = width; sH = height; newW = sW/5;

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Заголовок диалога");

        Bitmap imageForIcon = getResizedBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.homecolor), newW, newW);
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), imageForIcon);
        dialog.setIcon(drawable);
        dialog.setMessage("\nТекст диалога\n");

        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
}
```

Результат работы в Андроид 4.2.2

[image: Иконка хорошо видна]

Результат работы в Андроид 5.0.0

[image: Иконку не видно :(]

Comment: Кто-то изменил и теперь результаты работы не считываются! Т.к. я выкладывал скрины впервые, не знал, что их нельзя выкладывать явно, а надо загружать в файлообменники. Но, файлообменники иногда глючат)

Comment: Попробуйте задать иконку явно, без предварительного пересжатия .setIcon(R.drawable.homecolor);

Comment: Уважаемый Антон! Этот танец с бубнами как раз и затевался из-за того, что явно указывать иконку не устраивает!

Comment: Не зная предыстории, отбрасывая все лишнее, проще решить проблему. Возможно проще сохранить иконку под размеры экрана(аналогично раскидыванию ic_laucher) 32 × 32 (mdpi)
 48 × 48 (hdpi)
64 × 64 (xhdpi)
96 × 96 (xxhdpi)
128 × 128 (xxxhdpi)

Comment: Ваше решение - на первый взгляд простое. На самом же деле, лучше один раз написать одну программу и больше к этой теме не возвращаться, чем каждый раз готовить 6-8 видов картинок и рассовывать их по папкам. Более того: устройств с разными параметрами экрана одного из dpi - много.

Comment: Названное вами "ваше решение" - рекомендуемая практика андроид-разработки. Ваше решение только на первый взгляд простое, на самом деле оно хуже заранее подготовленных под нужные разрешения иконок. И во первых - никто не говорил, что разработчиком быть легко, рутины в этой работе очень много, во вторых - подготовкой изображений под нужные разрешения и раскладыванию их по папкам занимаются специально приготовленные для этих целей инструменты IDE. Опять же, разработчик, ставящий в приоритет собственные удобства\лень против оптимизации приложения - плохой разработчик.

Answer (score 3):

В стиле material design не используются иконки в заголовках диалогов, это особенности стиля [(Material dialogs)](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html). Использование заголовков в Alert диалогах там вообще не приветствуется.

Если сильно надо, можно задать свой layout со своим заголовком, либо попробовать добавить иконку в текст в ImageSpan